# Jquery - Remove Special characters from XML Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have this simple javascript code that searches for specific strings in a xml attribute. It already has case insensitive, so if I search for the string **"Técnico"** or **"técnico"** it returns the same results.

But I want to search without special characters, so instead of **"Técnico"**, if I use **"Tecnico"** or **"tecnico"** it should return the same results. Could you please help me? Below is the code I'm using.

```
var texto = $("#pesq_profissao").val();   
var resultado; 
var valor = $(xml).find('profissao').filter(function() {
            return ($(this).attr('codigo') || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(texto.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            });

resultado = valor;
```

**EDIT**

Still didn't work, as a matter of fact, the previous search stop working, I had to roll back that development. But I still left an example of what I did. As you can see in the `if(readCookie('googtrans')=='/pt/pt')` I used the `accent_fold()` function, but I couldn't make it work, in the chrome console doesn't show any error, but after debugging, I saw that search is not returning the values it was suppose to return. Can you guys help me again?

Oh, and I convinced the senior to allow me to post the entire search function, the function name is in portuguese, so function *pequisa* means function *search*. So here it goes.

```
var accentMap = {  'á':'a', 'é':'e', 'í':'i','ó':'o','ú':'u'};
function accent_fold(s){
 if (!s) { return ''; }
   var ret = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      if(!accentMap[s.charAt(i)])
        ret += s.charAt(i);
     else
        ret += accentMap[s.charAt(i)];
     }
       return ret;
     }

 function pesquisa() {
$("#profissao").empty();
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
 var resultado;
$xml = $(xmlDoc);
var texto = $("#pesq_profissao").val();

if (texto.length > 2) {
    if( readCookie('googtrans')=='/pt/pt'){
            var valor = $(xml).find('profissao').filter(function() {
            var returns = accent_fold(($(this).attr('codigo') || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(texto.toLowerCase()) > -1);
            return returns
            });

        resultado = valor;
    }else if(readCookie('googtrans')== null)
    {
            var valor = $(xml).find('profissao').filter(function() {
            return ($(this).attr('codigo') || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(texto.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            });

        resultado = valor;

    }else if(readCookie('googtrans')=='/pt/en')
    {
            var valor = $(xml).find('profissao').filter(function() {
            return ($(this).attr('codigo') || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(texto.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            });

        resultado = valor;
    }else
    {
        var valor = $(xml).find('profissao').filter(function() {
            return ($(this).attr('codigo') || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(texto.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            });

        resultado = valor;
    }


    $.each(resultado, function (index, value) {
        jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
        $parents = $(value).parents().reverse();
        var new_node = new node($(value));

        // caminho ate a raiz
        $.each($parents, function (index, value) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            $(li).append($(value).attr("descricao"));
            $(div).addClass("cae_open");
            $(div).append(li);
            $("#profissao").append(div);
        });

        // no folha
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        var a = document.createElement('li');
        $(a).append($(value).attr("descricao"));
        $(a).addClass("transbox");
        $(div).addClass("cae_sel");
        $(div).append(a);

        link = document.createElement('a');
        Sigla = document.createTextNode(new_node.Sigla);
        link.appendChild(Sigla);


        $(link).attr("href", new_node.url);
        $(link).attr('target', '_blank');
        a.appendChild(link);

        $(div).click(function () {
            parametersValue = jQuery.makeArray($(value).attr("codigo"));
            FinalizaPesquisa();
        });
        $("#profissao").append(div);
    });

    if (resultado.length == 0) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        $(span).append("Não existem resultados para a sua pesquisa.");
        $("#profissao").append(span);
    }

}
else {
    buildTree(root);
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check [here](http://alistapart.com/article/accent-folding-for-auto-complete). It has what you want.

**EDIT**: `Xml` parse and sample **js**  added.

```js
var parser, xmlDoc;
var text = "<bookstore><book>" +
"<title>Evérydáy Italían</title>" +
"<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>" +
"<year>2005</year>" +
"</book></bookstore>";

if (window.DOMParser) {
  parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
} else {
  xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async = false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(text); 
} 

var accentMap = {
  'á':'a', 'é':'e', 'í':'i','ó':'o','ú':'u'
};

document.write(accent_fold(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue));

function accent_fold(s){
  if (!s) { return ''; }
  var ret = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
   if(!accentMap[s.charAt(i)])
          ret += s.charAt(i);
         else
         ret += accentMap[s.charAt(i)];
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Interesting one! Can you use this to solve OP's problem as well?

Comment: Sorry! OP's problem?

Comment: OP shared a code which is not working. Tell OP how should he used this idea to solve his problem.

Comment: @Krezus Thanks for answering so quickly, for What I have seen, this should work. But even with the examples illustrated in the website and github I'm having difficulty in applying this to my example. Could you please help?

Comment: @gurvinder372 my code is not working ? well I can say why, I only showing a portion of the code, unfortunately I can't show more. It's missing the xml parsing before the .find(). But I can tell you it's working right now, since it's on a Local Machine and I tested it before posting.

Comment: @airesmenezes if your code is working already as per your expectations then why have you posted a question?

Comment: If you accept as a answer after check, I will be grateful @AiresMenezes

Comment: @krezus it didn't work, I posted the entire function. I hope it helps you, helping me :) Or maybe, I'm missing something simple.